# mongodb keeps sucking memory

Tags: database, mongodb

version is 4.0.6 community.

1 mongos, 1 config server, 1 shard on an 8 core 32gb ram ubuntu16.04 server.

wiredTiger's cache size is set to 5gb (tried 4gb, 6gb, 10gb, 16gb, all the same behavior).

total data set is 40gb, total index set is around 10gb and not all active.

after 20 hours:

db.serverStatus().tcmalloc.tcmalloc.formattedString shows:

```
MALLOC:    22843995584 (21785.7 MiB) Bytes in use by application
MALLOC: +   1307635712 ( 1247.1 MiB) Bytes in page heap freelist
MALLOC: +    766107360 (  730.6 MiB) Bytes in central cache freelist
MALLOC: +        39168 (    0.0 MiB) Bytes in transfer cache freelist
MALLOC: +    210563680 (  200.8 MiB) Bytes in thread cache freelists
MALLOC: +    200433920 (  191.1 MiB) Bytes in malloc metadata
MALLOC:   ------------
MALLOC: =  25328775424 (24155.4 MiB) Actual memory used (physical + swap)
MALLOC: +   1736736768 ( 1656.3 MiB) Bytes released to OS (aka unmapped)
MALLOC:   ------------
MALLOC: =  27065512192 (25811.7 MiB) Virtual address space used
MALLOC:
MALLOC:        2979451              Spans in use
MALLOC:           1147              Thread heaps in use
MALLOC:           4096              Tcmalloc page size
```

mongostat shows:

```
insert query update delete getmore command dirty  used flushes vsize   res qrw arw net_in net_out conn       set repl                time
 6  5917    603      1       0    82|0  3.8% 78.9%       0 27.6G 23.6G 0|0 2|0  1.45m   4.31m 1094 air_shard  PRI Jun  6 02:51:18.205
 2  5864    605     *0       0   102|0  3.9% 78.9%       0 27.6G 23.6G 0|0 1|2  1.44m   4.29m 1094 air_shard  PRI Jun  6 02:51:19.205
 4  5555    684     *0       0   100|0  4.1% 79.0%       0 27.6G 23.6G 0|1 2|0  1.41m   4.08m 1094 air_shard  PRI Jun  6 02:51:20.204
 2  5430    624     *0       0    71|0  4.3% 79.0%       0 27.6G 23.6G 0|0 1|0  1.36m   4.05m 1094 air_shard  PRI Jun  6 02:51:21.205
 3  5606    807     *0       0    77|0  4.5% 79.0%       0 27.6G 23.6G 0|0 1|2  1.48m   4.03m 1095 air_shard  PRI Jun  6 02:51:22.203
 2  5809    685     *0       0    93|0  4.6% 79.1%       0 27.6G 23.6G 0|0 1|0  1.47m   4.21m 1095 air_shard  PRI Jun  6 02:51:23.203
 2  5701    715     *0       0   116|0  4.7% 79.1%       0 27.6G 23.6G 1|0 1|0  1.46m   4.15m 1095 air_shard  PRI Jun  6 02:51:24.205
 1  6082    649     *0       0    80|0  4.8% 79.1%       0 27.6G 23.6G 0|0 1|0  1.50m   4.42m 1095 air_shard  PRI Jun  6 02:51:25.208
 6  6016    727      1       0    90|0  5.0% 79.2%       0 27.6G 23.6G 0|0 2|0  1.52m   4.36m 1095 air_shard  PRI Jun  6 02:51:26.202
 1  5797    698     *0       0    97|0  5.1% 79.1%       0 27.6G 23.6G 0|0 3|0  1.47m   4.22m 1095 air_shard  PRI Jun  6 02:51:27.203
```

db.serverStatus().wiredTiger.cache (after 24 hours (tcmalloc 28gb))

```
{
"application threads page read from disk to cache count" : 8213668,
"application threads page read from disk to cache time (usecs)" : 2081239762,
"application threads page write from cache to disk count" : 23636538,
"application threads page write from cache to disk time (usecs)" : 373385784,
"bytes belonging to page images in the cache" : 3678160542,
"bytes belonging to the cache overflow table in the cache" : 182,
"bytes currently in the cache" : 4283010946,
"bytes dirty in the cache cumulative" : 708202598553,
"bytes not belonging to page images in the cache" : 604850403,
"bytes read into cache" : 142476442004,
"bytes written from cache" : 493106511738,
"cache overflow cursor application thread wait time (usecs)" : 0,
"cache overflow cursor internal thread wait time (usecs)" : 0,
"cache overflow score" : 0,
"cache overflow table entries" : 0,
"cache overflow table insert calls" : 0,
"cache overflow table remove calls" : 0,
"checkpoint blocked page eviction" : 15206,
"eviction calls to get a page" : 24221700,
"eviction calls to get a page found queue empty" : 266843,
"eviction calls to get a page found queue empty after locking" : 281267,
"eviction currently operating in aggressive mode" : 0,
"eviction empty score" : 0,
"eviction passes of a file" : 20120988,
"eviction server candidate queue empty when topping up" : 109812,
"eviction server candidate queue not empty when topping up" : 286120,
"eviction server evicting pages" : 0,
"eviction server slept, because we did not make progress with eviction" : 2053931,
"eviction server unable to reach eviction goal" : 0,
"eviction state" : 32,
"eviction walk target pages histogram - 0-9" : 19436220,
"eviction walk target pages histogram - 10-31" : 283191,
"eviction walk target pages histogram - 128 and higher" : 0,
"eviction walk target pages histogram - 32-63" : 157161,
"eviction walk target pages histogram - 64-128" : 244416,
"eviction walks abandoned" : 2151028,
"eviction walks gave up because they restarted their walk twice" : 15229599,
"eviction walks gave up because they saw too many pages and found no candidates" : 975857,
"eviction walks gave up because they saw too many pages and found too few candidates" : 37269,
"eviction walks reached end of tree" : 33311884,
"eviction walks started from root of tree" : 18426527,
"eviction walks started from saved location in tree" : 1694461,
"eviction worker thread active" : 4,
"eviction worker thread created" : 0,
"eviction worker thread evicting pages" : 23588288,
"eviction worker thread removed" : 0,
"eviction worker thread stable number" : 0,
"failed eviction of pages that exceeded the in-memory maximum count" : 6712,
"failed eviction of pages that exceeded the in-memory maximum time (usecs)" : 35676,
"files with active eviction walks" : 0,
"files with new eviction walks started" : 18082285,
"force re-tuning of eviction workers once in a while" : 0,
"hazard pointer blocked page eviction" : 22282,
"hazard pointer check calls" : 23735427,
"hazard pointer check entries walked" : 1040247438,
"hazard pointer maximum array length" : 2,
"in-memory page passed criteria to be split" : 22349,
"in-memory page splits" : 6499,
"internal pages evicted" : 96859,
"internal pages split during eviction" : 99,
"leaf pages split during eviction" : 19160,
"maximum bytes configured" : 5368709120,
"maximum page size at eviction" : 8388389,
"modified pages evicted" : 17068834,
"modified pages evicted by application threads" : 0,
"operations timed out waiting for space in cache" : 0,
"overflow pages read into cache" : 0,
"page split during eviction deepened the tree" : 0,
"page written requiring cache overflow records" : 0,
"pages currently held in the cache" : 183243,
"pages evicted because they exceeded the in-memory maximum count" : 6499,
"pages evicted because they exceeded the in-memory maximum time (usecs)" : 2617799,
"pages evicted because they had chains of deleted items count" : 45671,
"pages evicted because they had chains of deleted items time (usecs)" : 82342,
"pages evicted by application threads" : 88378,
"pages queued for eviction" : 39570786,
"pages queued for urgent eviction" : 17086,
"pages queued for urgent eviction during walk" : 3747,
"pages read into cache" : 8214055,
"pages read into cache after truncate" : 831,
"pages read into cache after truncate in prepare state" : 0,
"pages read into cache requiring cache overflow entries" : 0,
"pages read into cache requiring cache overflow for checkpoint" : 0,
"pages read into cache skipping older cache overflow entries" : 0,
"pages read into cache with skipped cache overflow entries needed later" : 0,
"pages read into cache with skipped cache overflow entries needed later by checkpoint" : 0,
"pages requested from the cache" : 4862957119,
"pages seen by eviction walk" : 299339913,
"pages selected for eviction unable to be evicted" : 53658,
"pages walked for eviction" : 12906348724,
"pages written from cache" : 38874718,
"pages written requiring in-memory restoration" : 305125,
"percentage overhead" : 8,
"tracked bytes belonging to internal pages in the cache" : 102426754,
"tracked bytes belonging to leaf pages in the cache" : 4180584192,
"tracked dirty bytes in the cache" : 288426173,
"tracked dirty pages in the cache" : 16896,
"unmodified pages evicted" : 6596106
```

}

tcmalloc keeps allocating memory. finally it will go swapping and lagging and die.

my apps use python + pymongo(1000 connections).

before starting swapping, the apps are all doing well.

in my mind total memory usage should be 5gb(wiredTiger cache setting) + at most 2~3gb's mongodb basic usage(for connection maintaining etc... )

don't know why it keeps allocating memory.

Comment: What are the wiredtiger stats? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#must-my-working-set-size-fit-ram

Comment: run mongodb 4.2.7 with same config. problems gone.